# js display options based on other option selected

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a select field that contains shipping lines as follows

```
<select>
    <option >cma</option>
   <option>uafl</option>
</select>
```

and another select field that contains ships as follows

```
<select>
    <option >apulia</option>
    <option>costa</option>
    <option >beinjin</option>
    <option>union</option>
</select>
```

when a user selects a shipping line say CMA i want the select option containing ships, to display ships that associates with CMA only say COSTA and BEINJIN

and these data will be pulled from mysql database.

please help, i will much appreciate it. thanks.

Comment: Where's your attempted code?

Comment: Use AJAX and onchange function of jQuery

Comment: Where does your data come from? From a database? How are they link together? If then, can you provide your structure for it?

Answer (score 0):

#### Note:

- You need to use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to achieve your goal
- I will be using jQuery, a javascript library which you can download [here](https://jquery.com/download/) then store it in your project folder

Code (select.php):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <!-- REPLACE NECESSARY JS FILE DEPENDING ON THE VERSION YOU HAVE DOWNLOADED -->
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){ /* START JQUERY */
      $("#base-select").change(function(e){ /* EVERYTIME A SHIP IS SELECTED */
        e.preventDefault(); /* PREVENT FROM REFRESHING THE PAGE */
        var base = $("#base-select").val(); /* STORE THE SELECTED SHIP TO THIS VARIABLE */
        var dataString = "base="+base; /* STORE THE DATA IN A DATA STRING */

        $.ajax({ /* START THE AJAX */
          type: "POST", /* METHOD YOU WILL BE USING TO SUBMIT VALUE OF THE SELECTED SHIP */
          url: "get-options.php", /* THE TARGET FILE ON WHERE YOU WILL PASS THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED SHIP */
          data: dataString, /* THE DATA YOU WILL BE PASSING */
          success: function(result){
            $("#select").empty().append(result); /* CLEAR THE CURRENT OPTIONS OF THE SECOND SELECT FIELD AND UPDATE DEPENDING ON THE SELECTED SHIPS */
          } /* END OF SUCCESS */
        }); /* END OF AJAX */

      }); /* END OF CHANGE FUNCTION */
    });

  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <select id="base-select">
    <option disabled selected>Select Shipping Line</option>
    <option value="1">CMA</option>
    <option value="2">UAFL</option>
  </select>

  <select id="select">
    <option disable>Select first a Shipping Line</option>
  </select>

</body>
</html>
```

get-options.php:

```
<?php

  if(!empty($_POST["base"])){
    if($_POST["base"] == 1){
      ?>
        <option>COSTA</option>
        <option>BEIJIN</option>
      <?php
    }
    else if($_POST["base"] == 2){
      ?>
        <option>APULIA</option>
        <option>UNION</option>
      <?php
    }
  }    

?>
```

Comment: Thanks alot @logan , it works like a charm on a seperate page which is not in my project, but once i intergrate it in a page which includes other js sripts like ng_all.js , it doesnt work, can you assist me othat please.

Comment: and i have a script as

Comment: @RashidAmour - if you remove the `ng_all.js`, does it work? Is it important? Or maybe you have other scripts that conflicts with the script I have provided?

Comment: @RashidAmour - I have updated my answer. I separate the file where we get the options, because it will conflict the outputs to get if it is also in the same file. Then update the link from `select.php` to `get-options.php` in AJAX script.

Comment: if i remove ng_all.js it does work, okay i will try that idea and get back to you, again thanks :)

Comment: @RashidAmour - it means that the `ng_all.js` conflicts with the script that I have provided.